# What is the best CMS for .net?

Tags: cms, asp.net, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I need advice on the best CMS for an online shopping website in ASP.NET 4.0. Any advice?

Comment: Are you considering all CMS's, commercial and open-source?

Comment: What particular features are you looking for. Because talking of *best* CMS without giving more details begs for this question getting closed as subjective.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/)

Answer (score 1):

See [Web App Gallery's CMS category](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/categories.aspx?category=ContentMgmt). There are quite a few with short description and user ratings.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Kentico](http://kentico.com). It is full featured and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "best". You must have a matrix of functional requirements and product features, and a matrix of non-functional requirements and qualities. The ideal products *for your needs* comes out of that. Without enumerating those on your side, there's no way to even start.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the annual CMS report produced by waterandstone.com - [2010 report](http://www.waterandstone.com/book/2010-open-source-cms-market-share-report) - you will at least get the basis for an impartial decision.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend AxCMS.net it's free but not open source.
Also for online store I can suggest [MojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com) and [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.net)

Answer (score 0):

**Composite C1 CMS** is free open source and the [best rated .net CMS at CodePlex](http://bit.ly/BestRatedCmsOnCodePlex). It can integrate with nopCommerce (free open source and [best rated shop at CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?tagName=shop&sortBy=CurrentReleaseRating)). Both are .net 4.0 based.

You can get it from the [Composite C1 website](http://www.composite.net/) or the Windows Web App Gallery.

[image: Screenshot from Composite C1 UI]

As John state below, I'm on the Composite C1 dev team, so rely on the CodePlex ratings, not my word ;-)

Comment: If you're going to promote your own product you should be upfront about it.

Comment: I didn't downvote because you do contribute here. I just wanted to encourage you to do full disclosure. That helps to avoid an air of spaminess.